# Selenium WebDriver can't find element by link text

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select an element that includes an anchor, but the text is buried in a paragraph inside of a div.  Here's the HTML I'm working with:

```
<a class="item" ng-href="#/catalog/90d9650a36988e5d0136988f03ab000f/category/DATABASE_SERVERS/service/90cefc7a42b3d4df0142b52466810026" href="#/catalog/90d9650a36988e5d0136988f03ab000f/category/DATABASE_SERVERS/service/90cefc7a42b3d4df0142b52466810026">
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 item-list-image">
<img ng-src="csa/images/library/Service_Design.png" src="csa/images/library/Service_Design.png">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-8">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <p>
    <strong class="ng-binding">Smoke Sequential</strong>
    </p>
```

The code I'm using to try to snag it is targeting the "Smoke Sequential" text with:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText(service)).click();
```

Where the variable 'service' holds "Smoke Sequential" in it.  When I run it, I get the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Smoke Sequential"}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem might be in the rest of the html, the part that you didn't post.

With this example (I just closed the open tags):

```
<a class="item" ng-href="#/catalog/90d9650a36988e5d0136988f03ab000f/category/DATABASE_SERVERS/service/90cefc7a42b3d4df0142b52466810026" href="#/catalog/90d9650a36988e5d0136988f03ab000f/category/DATABASE_SERVERS/service/90cefc7a42b3d4df0142b52466810026">
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 item-list-image">
<img ng-src="csa/images/library/Service_Design.png" src="csa/images/library/Service_Design.png">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-8">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <p>
    <strong class="ng-binding">Smoke Sequential</strong>
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
</a>
```

I was able to find the element without trouble with:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Smoke Sequential")).click();
```

If there is more text inside the  element, you could try a find by partial link text:

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Sequential")).click();
```

Comment: This is ultimately what I used.  It turned out partialLinkText snagged it for reasons I can't figure out and don't want to burn time on.  Thanks everyone! :-)

Comment: In my case it was not a partial link, but the text for the link got a space. A trim() solved the problem. It also seems that the driver for Firefox is tolerant for such spaces, but Chrome does not accept it.

Answer (score 5):

Use xpath and text()

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//strong[contains(text(),'" + service +"')]"));
```

Comment: I would do this, except specify an anchor tag, rather than strong - driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//a[contains(text(),'" + service +"')]"));

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to have  `<a> </a>` tags   so selenium might not be able to detect it as a link.

You may try and use

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ng-binding']")).click();
```

if this is the only element in that page with this class .

Comment: it does have an `<a/>` tag in there: `<a class="item" ng-href="#/catalog/90d9650a36988e5d013...`

Comment: Also, i'm downvoting because the code you specify THERE, would click the `<strong />`.   Clicking a `<strong /`> renders Nothing unless the app specifically expects the user to click strong, but since it's wrapped in a hyperlink, that's not the case here.

Comment: The original post said they wanted to click on the "Smoke Sequential" link and not the <a> on the first line of the snippet.

Comment: The anchor is what needs to be clicked.  I didn't include the closing tag for the anchor because there are a bunch of other divs that would just consume space, but it's there.

It's also not the only element with the ng-binding label.  It's off of a list that could be dozens, if not hundreds, deep.

Comment: Sorry, let me try that again: I just need a clickable element.  The named one I'm aiming for happens to be the only one I will know ahead of time since other identifiers are created in ways I can't track.

Comment: Talkleus: how is service related to the anchor tag?

Comment: Sorry, one more.  I'm also trying to avoid x-path because this html is being changed not infrequently and while the name in the element will be consistent, other aspects might not be.

Comment: The anchor tag contains the href element that I'm wanting to exercise, but otherwise, they're unrelated.  I just wasn't thinking when I typed that part and was past the 5 minutes when I went to correct it.

Comment: Hey, would a cssSelector approach work here?  I haven't really used it at all, so I'm not sure what the correct formatting would be.

Comment: @sircapsalot Can u undo the downvoting since the OP's question was not clear ?

Answer (score 0):

A CSS selector approach could definitely work here. Try:

```
driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("a.item")).Click();
```

This will not work if there are other anchors before this one of the class item. You can better specify the exact element if you do something like "#my_table > a.item" where my_table is the id of a table that the anchor is a child of.

Comment: It won't necessarily be first on the list.  That list of items varies based on what's populated to a database that sits behind it.  a.item isn't unique to it either.  That class will be shared with each item on the list.  That descriptor that posts up, in this case "Smoke Sequential", is the only unique aspect of the item.

Comment: The string input probably isn't formatted correctly, but what about something like: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("strong:contains(\"" + service + "\")")).click();

Comment: It isn't, sadly.  That text in the strong tag is the only truly unique thing in the entire tree.

Comment: CSS selectors probably can't help you then. Especially if the location of the link you are trying to click is volatile as you say. CSS selectors are best when you know where to look in the html.

Answer (score 0):

```
find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='class name']")
```

is a great solution