# How to use Selenium to grab nested LinkText?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium in C# to click on a link called 'Store Locator'. My current code is as follows but does not click on the link:

```
IWebElement storeLink = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Store Locator"));
```

Here is the original HTML, notice there is a span element nested in the  tag, not sure if this makes a difference.

```
<a href="/site/olspage.jsp?id=cat12090&amp;type=page&amp;rdct=n" data-lid="hdr_stl"><span class="header-icon-storeFinder" aria-hidden="true"></span>Store Locator</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver can't find element by link text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380720/selenium-webdriver-cant-find-element-by-link-text)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the link is hidden. If even `Selenium` finds the link it will not be able to interact directly. In that case JavaScript is your only option

```
By xpath = By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'Store Locator')]");
IWebelement element = driver.FindElement(xpath);
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(@"arguments[0].click();",element);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for sure.

```
IWebElement storeLink = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Store Locator"));
storeLink.click();
```