# Can I use a string variable when using LinkText?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, selenium, linktext

Using Selenium in Visual Studio. I'm trying to click on a item in a list. The item has a unique ID.

`CA-41107005-00000040`

Instead of referring to the actual ID-number I want to make the test more dynamic by referring to a string variable that will store a item ID. I call this variable: `changeActionNumber`

The HTML code for the item looks like this:
[image]

I have tried clicking on the item like this:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.LinkText($"{changeActionNumber}"))).Click();
```

And also like this:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.LinkText(changeActionNumber))).Click();
```

But both cases gave the same error:

```
Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 10 seconds
  ----> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"CA-41107005-00000040"}
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.75)
```

Is it not possible to use variables when using LinkText?

Comment: Looking at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20380720/578411 it seems that By.LinkText is very strict about page structure. While I would expect the code you have to work with the html you've shown, there might be other parts of the page that are not playing nice for you.

Comment: what happens if u use string constant instead of variable?

Comment: Is this element inside an IFRAME?

Comment: Please check if there any iframe as @JeffC has mentioned.

Comment: This should work. A couple of debugging steps you could try:
Add a sleep before finding the element (note, you should use a wait instead of sleep eventually)
Print out the variable changeActionNumber before doing the find.

Comment: @JeffC This seems to be an iframe issue. I will create a new question since LinkText and the possibility to use variables is not really in question anymore. The reason it's not working is that the iframe is not recognized when I try to switch to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using variables in LinkText was not the problem.

The problem was that my driver was not focused on the correct iframe and could therefore never find a matching LinkText value.

I changed my iframe focus like this:

```
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultFrame();

driver.SwitchTo().Frame("firstiframe");
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("secondiframe");
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("thirdiframe");
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("ECMMyChangeActions");
```

And after that I could use LinkText with a variable without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below `xapth`

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Xpath("//a[text()='" +changeActionNumber + ']"))).Click();
```

OR

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Xpath("//a[contains(.,'" +changeActionNumber + ')]"))).Click();
```

Comment: I like this answer because it's likely your element is jsut not shown on the page yet. The variable substitution should work as you have in the question.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, LinkText selector looks for link text as it is presented on page, not in html code. So if this text is additionally formatted before being displayed on page, like letters to lower case or special symbols removed, you must consider this.

If you want to work with text as it presented in code, try xpath instead

```
By.XPath(string.Format(".//a[.='{0}']", changeActionNumber))
```